# Python and OpenCV - Determine Correct Frame Rate of Captured Streaming Video

Tags: python, opencv, video, video-capture, capture

I’m using OpenCV in a Python environment to capture a video stream from an external source, display the video, and write the video to a file.  The video stream can come from different video sources.  I need to write the video using the exact same frame rate as the incoming video (e.g., 60 fps, 29.97 fps, 30 fps, etc.).

Because the streaming video does not have the frame rate embedded in the stream, I need to determine the correct frame rate.  I have tried suggestions by others of sampling some frames then divide the number of captured frames by the elapsed time.  For me, this results in a frame rate that is close, but not close enough.

When I capture the video with VLC Media Player, VLC determines the frame rate correctly.

Here is the Python script that I’m currently using.  It buffers 500 frames to compute the frame rate and then starts writing the video while continuing to capture (with a 500 frame delay).  (VLS capture/write doesn’t have a noticeable delay.)

Foremost importance to me – correctly determine the frame rate of the incoming video stream.  Second importance – I want to write the video with minimum delay after capture.

Any suggestions?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from time import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
frame_width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
frame_height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX')
kount = 0
delay = 500
buffer = []
start = time()
while(cap.isOpened()):  
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        kount += 1
        buffer.append(frame)
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if kount >= delay:
            if kount == delay:
                end = time()
                fps = kount / (end - start)
                out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, fps, (frame_width,frame_height))
            out.write(buffer[kount-delay])
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            for i in range(kount - delay, kount):
                out.write(buffer[i])
            break
    else:
        break
print("Frames Per Second = ", fps)
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Have  you tried w/ mpeg4 instead? Also, here is a short on how to stream FPS on specific instances of streams: https://linuxhint.com/show_fps_counter_linux_games/ .